# How to recalculate automatic weights for single bones?

Tags: bones

After I edited an already weighted model and its armature, the pose mode doesn't grab the limbs the right way anymore. 
Is there a way to recalculate weights for  ***single bones***? Because I already edited the weights for other parts of the mesh and don't want to redo that again.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Weight paint mode, select the pose bones you want to recompute the weight and press:
W > Assign automatic from bones

Comment: Heads up for 2019: You can't select bones in weight paint mode in Blender 2.80

Comment: The new workflow is you select the armature, multiple select the mesh, then go to weight paint mode, and then you can select individual bones with Ctrl-click (alt+shift+click for multiple bones)
The W hotkey seems to be no more but the ption is in the Weights menu between View and Brush (In 3D-View top header)

Answer (score 8):

(For August 2019 2.8)
First select your bones, then shift-select your mesh. Make sure your mesh is selected second.

Now go into weight paint mode and ctrl-select whichever bone you want to adjust the weight for.

Press f3 to open the operator search and search for 'Weight From Bones'

Then select it and select 'Automatic'

Since you can select whichever bones you want now during weight painting you can reapply your automatic weights to all your bones this way.

Comment: I didn't want "automatic weight" so first 2 steps were enough and wokred great

Answer (score 7):

ctrl-select bone in weight paint mode did not work for me in Blender 2.8 . The following works for me though:

1. Select the pose bones in ***Pose Mode***.
2. Select armature, then mesh in ***Object Mode***.
3. Goto ***Weight Paint***, select all area by pressing ***A*** (or only selected area you want)
4. At the top left corner of 3D view, look for ***Weights*** menu and click ***Assign Automatic From Bones***
5. Done! You can verify the new weight by selecting the ***Vertex Group*** of your bone in ***Object Data*** at the ***Properties*** window

Comment: This way works fine in May 2020.

Answer (score 6):

Go in pose mode and select the bone that you want to weight paint.

Then select your mesh and switch into Weight paint mode.

Press W and then you choose "assign automatic from bones"

Answer (score -1):

Blender 3.1:

1. Go to pose mode
2. Select all meshes
3. Ctrl-click armature in outliner (add to selection)
4. In viewport: `ctrl+p` > `armature deform (with automatic weights)`