# Automatic Weights not recalculating after moving Bone

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting

I am working with a fairly simple rig, as I'm pretty new to rigging/animation in general.

I created my bones, and later parented my mesh to the armature with automatic weights.

Later, I wasn't happy with some of the bone positions/sizes/orientations, so I moved them around in Edit mode.

I visited [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34898/how-to-recalculate-automatic-weights-for-single-bones), in what I thought would be a simple way to recalculate the automatic weights. However, nothing appears to happen? Am I doing something incorrectly, or is there some type of problem keeping these weights from being regenerated.

In the provided gif, note that the weights stay the same after the bone is dragged way out of position.

[image]

Comment: You may want to show the [mode] (object, edit, weight paint) in the future, even if you feel it may be obvious.   Your bones may be in X-Ray which makes sense.  The viewer of your question can only guess the position of the bone.  Quad View can allow the viewer to more fully see the position of bones.

Comment: It would be easier for me to see the before and after image with a label in addtion to than the video alone.  The menu choices are quite small.

Comment: I would also advise you not assigning dramatically new position to bones and using the steps you outlined above.

Comment: Please state what mode you are in.  Perhaps I have not taken the time to determine you mode.  At this point I am looking at your question rather than testing in Blender.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger all very good points! although it turns I had created the problem myself (see below answer)

Comment: Yes this points out your original information was too concise.  Then I could ask you for the information and periodically check to see if you have added it.  More time consumption. Yet a total recreation of the data would obviate the need to know such details.  Its adds a little value you know the cause.  However your technique is not something I would advise.  The locking also appears ill advised in this particular example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the [other answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34898/how-to-recalculate-automatic-weights-for-single-bones) referenced is correct, with an important caveat.

When automatically assigning weights, a vertex group is generated. I had my vertex groups locked so I didn't accidentally mess them up. As a result, this kept the weight paint data from being updated. If the groups are unlocked (or removed), the automatic generation should work.

In short, make sure the vertex groups are unlocked on the mesh you want to deform when automatically assigning weights.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be in edit mode and not pose mode.

Suggestion. Manual weight painting is time costly.  If you have zero or or close to zero investment in manual weight painting then simply delete your existing [bone weight] work and start fresh to be time effective.  You have the luxury at the moment of discarding what might be a mistake rather than doing a sequence of recovery steps.

Simply assign automatic weights all over again.  That is 8 seconds of work. In your situation, the action of

Parent Armature with automatic weights <kbd>Control-P</kbd>

can be done many times since you are not losing time costly manual weight painting.

Please know that a large bone next to a small bone will have generally more influence except where the small bone is extremely close to the mesh.