# Reassigning Automatic weights on single bone not working properly

Tags: armature, bones, transforms, weight-painting, vertex-groups

I'm new to blender and I'm trying to make my character move properly
let me explain my problem image by image:-

1. let's say this is the default armature assigned weight when making parent
   [image]

---

2. now let's say I messed up my weight painting
   and want **ONLY THAT VERTEX** group to go back to default
   [image]

---

3. So I follow the steps on [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/159197) question
   and this is the result I get:
   [image]

   Where as I thought that the result should be the same as the first picture
   Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? and how to achieve the desired results?

Comment: You might have Automatically Normalize checked in the weight settings in the side panel.

Comment: @MartyFouts incredibly sorry for the late response but yes I have auto normalize checked